# Notch Filter with high Q easy to realize on breadboard

Tags: active-filter

So I have to get rid of two frequencies in an audio signal. I use for that two notch filters.

[image: Two filters (fliege)]

According to my spice simulation I should get pretty good negative gain:
[image]

The problem is the two frequencies already have a gain compared to the audio signal of around 15 dB and I loose some gain in practice when I get the frequency response of the physical filters on the impedance analyzer. I still get an audible buzz. Any clues on how to get rid of those two frequencies?

Comment: Do you have a reference link to the circuit you have designed?

Comment: Do you mean a net list?

Comment: I'm wondering how you got to that circuit topology - is it based on something on the internet?

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to measure the actual response of your filters.

I'd expect that the notch frequency is inversely proportional to the value of the two .220 uF capacitors. If they have 10% tolerance, the notch can be off by as much as 10%, and that's not counting the resistor tolerances. If you're using 5% resistors, it gets even worse. In that case, the attenuation of the desired frequencies drops from 50 dB to about 6 dB.

If that's not bad enough, my simulations are nothing like yours. Please recheck your circuit. I'm getting a maximum attenuation of about 6 dB.

Comment: I rechecked my simulation and I am still getting the same results. I know I am going to get variation because I am using 5% resistors but the filter shouldn't be too sensitive. The problem is I need something like -80dB gain, twice what I have and I can't find resources on how to accomplish that.

Comment: Can you provide a link to your circuit source? And as for sensitivity, try rerunning your simulation with the resistors varying by 5% and the capacitors by 10%. For instance, set C1 to 200 nf and C2 to 240 nf, with similar changes in the other components.

Comment: Furthermore, I recommend http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slyt235/slyt235.pdf Particularly, "The depth of the notch obtainable in simulations like that shown in Fig. 1 is _not_ the depth that can be achieved with real-world components. The best that the designer can hope for is 40 to 50 dB."

Answer (score 0):

The notch frequency in a very similar circuit (I'm guessing it's actually the grandfather of this one) is determined by the RC network between his triplet resistors (2 "1R" & 1 "0.5R") and the 220nf caps. With that said, I'm missing the intent of using the 2nd pair of opamps in this circuit, since in the original circuit they're only intended to be used in order to *reduce* the specificity (Q) of the filter. According to my reading of: http://www.g3ynh.info/circuits/Bob_Batey/LB-5.pdf you would probably be better off simply using the first example circuit, of course using your computed R & C values, for each of your notch filters. Also, using a very high Q notch filter (Q=50 is claimed in that paper), tolerances need to be extremely tight, or there's a chance of missing the offending frequency almost completely & instead blocking a freq. that's "right next door."